# Convert images to pdf without compressing in Python

Tags: python, image, pdf, python-imaging-library

I want to club some images to create a pdf, but these images are in ppm format to save color information as jpg averages the color information in some parts of the image to compress the image. When converted to pdf using in python it creates the pdf using jpg conversion and the color is lost in some parts of the images. What should I do to retain the color?

This is the code I am using to create the pdf. I am using pillow to save multiple images in a pdf.

```
from PIL import Image
import os
import sys

x = sys.argv[1]
dir = "folder_directory"
l = []
i = 0
image_1 = Image.open(dir + "\\" + os.listdir(dir)[0])
im_1 = image_1.convert('RGB')
for image in os.listdir(dir):
    if i < 1:
        i += 1
        continue
    print(image)
    image_2 = Image.open(dir + "\\" + image)
    im_2 = image_2.convert('RGB')
    l.append(im_2)

im_1.save('saving_dir' + x +'.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=l)
```

Comment: I tried using TIFF format but the moment I compile it into a PDF the color profiles are lost. What I have understood from google is that PDF uses JPEG compression to create a PDF from images, but if you convert it manually there is an option to retain the image quality. Is it possible to do the same in python?

Comment: I am confused now. Your question says you want to combine a bunch of PPM format images (presumably **without** colour profiles as PPM doesn't support them) into a PDF, but in the comments you are suddenly talking about TIFF images **with** colour profiles and I don't know if you have morphed from wanting to do PPM->PDF, into wanting to do TIFF-PDF or PPM->TIFF. Please clarify what you really want. Thank you.